# urlpatterns - got 404 error

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am learning Django - a few days old. This is my problem.

http://mylocalhost.com:8000/home/  (stack overflow does not allow localhost so used a dummy full domain - mylocalhost.com instead)
works when I have this setting in urls.py

```
url(r'^home/','signups.views.home')
```

but does not work when I have this setting in urls.py

```
url(r'^$','signups.views.home',name='home')
```

I get the following error. #In the error below read mylocalhost.com as localhost. stackoverflow does not allow use of localhost.

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://mylocalhost.com:8000/home/

^$ [name='home']
The current URL, home/, didn't match any of these.

## My App structure

```
signups 
   admin.py
   __init__.py
   models.py
   tests.py
   views.py
```

## My views.py

```
enter code here
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext

def home(request):
    return render_to_response("signup.html", locals(),
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What errors, functionality or lack of functionality are you seeing? What do you expect it to do? I can tell you that the page won't be rendered for the url /home when you use ```url(r'^$','signups.views.home',name='home')``` because it doesn't match the regex. You may want to give the url part of the docs a read. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I have added more details on the error. Thanks for the link, going through it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't work. `r'^$'` matches the empty string. You are accesing with the relative path `/home`

Either make it also the regex url to be `r'^home/$'` or simply access `localhost:8000/` without the trailing `/home`

Comment: Thank you Mihai. Both of them works. I still have a lot of reading to do on url dispatcher. Thanks a ton.